# Ability to reduce the number of migrations after a while

Tags: laravel, migration

I maintain a [new but popular open source project](https://github.com/monicahq/monica) based on Laravel 5.4. After a few months, we already have 100+ migrations in the database folder.

In a year from now, we'll easily have more than 1000 migrations with the current rate of features.

Rails has the same concept of migrations, but when migrations are run, they are ran against `schema.rb`, which is updated after the migrations have been run. This is super nice because for new installations, they don't have to run all those migrations. Only one is necessary.

Is there a way in Laravel to do the same? Reduce the number of migrations after a given period of time, or between major version, have a base schema with only few migrations? Thanks!